# rails can I call model inside initializer files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.2

I need to call model inside rack_attack.rb file to check ip is blocklisted or not any idea how to do that?

```
/config/initializer/rack_atack.rb
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your migrations were already executed and the table for the model in question already exists, I believe you will be able to call your model from the initializer file as usual: `Model.method()`.

If you want to check if the table exists, you could do like this:

```
if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists? :settings
   Model.method()
end
```

Finally, if you want to make sure all other initializers have run before running this one, you could add the following code to your initializer:

```
# config/initializers/rack_attack.rb
Rails.configuration.after_initialize do
   Model.method()
end
```